# AutoHotkey: How can I emulate on XP, Win7 keyboard shortcuts Win + left/right arrows?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

On a Windows XP machine, I would like to emulate with AutoHotkey, Windows 7 keyboard shortcuts such as

- Windows logo key + Right arrow, which maximizes the app or desktop window to the right side of the screen
- Windows logo key + Left arrow, which maximizes the app or desktop window to the left side of the screen

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to user3419297 for the hints. I've done my homework:

```
;
; AutoHotkey Version:   1.0.48.5
; Language:             English
; Platform:             Windows XP
; Author:               gerdami
; License:              CC-By-SA 4.0 http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/
;
; Script Function:      WinMoveXPasWin7.ahk
; Version               1.0
; Date                  7 March 2015    


#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.


; ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Windows 7 keyboard shortcuts emulation
; Windows + Left arrow
; Windows + Right arrow
; Windows + Up arrow
; Windows + Down arrow
; ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
GetTaskBarDetails()
    {
        Global  ; If a function needs to access or create a large number of global variables, it can be defined to assume that all its variables are global 
        WinGetPos, TaskBarXpos, TaskBarYpos, TaskBarWidth, TaskBarHeight, ahk_class Shell_TrayWnd
        ;MsgBox, TaskBar details`nXpos:`t`t%TaskBarXpos%`nYpos:`t`t%TaskBarYpos%`nWidth:`t`t%TaskBarWidth%`nHeight:`t`t%TaskBarHeight%`nA_ScreenWidth:`t%A_ScreenWidth%`nA_ScreenHeight:`t%A_ScreenHeight%
        TaskBarXpos *=1
        TaskBarYpos *=1
        TaskBarWidth *=1
        TaskBarHeight *=1
    }   
#Left:: 
    {
    GetTaskBarDetails()
    ;MsgBox, TaskBarXpos:`t%TaskBarXpos%`nTaskBarYpos:`t%TaskBarYpos%`nTaskBarWidth:`t%TaskBarWidth%`nTaskBarHeight:`t%TaskBarHeight%`nA_ScreenWidth:`t%A_ScreenWidth%`nA_ScreenHeight:`t%A_ScreenHeight%
    If  (TaskBarWidth * 1) >= (A_ScreenWidth * 1)       ; TaskBar on top or bottom - I had to force to numbers for comparison
        {
            ;MsgBox TaskBar on top or bottom
            NewWidth := (A_ScreenWidth / 2)
            if  TaskBarYpos <= 0            ; TaskBar top
                {
                    ;MsgBox TaskBar top
                    NewXpos := 0
                    NewYpos := (TaskBarHeight + TaskBarYpos)
                    NewHeight := (A_ScreenHeight - (TaskBarHeight + TaskBarYpos))
                }   
            else                            ; TaskBar bottom
                {
                    ;MsgBox TaskBar bottom
                    NewXpos := 0
                    NewYpos := 0
                    NewHeight := TaskBarYpos
                }
        }
    else                                ; TaskBar left or right
        {
            ;MsgBox TaskBar TaskBar left or right
            NewHeight := A_ScreenHeight
            if  TaskBarXpos <= 0        ; TaskBar left
                {
                    ;MsgBox TaskBar left
                    NewXpos := (TaskBarWidth + TaskBarXpos)
                    NewYpos := 0
                    NewWidth := ((A_ScreenWidth - (TaskBarWidth + TaskBarXpos)) / 2)
                }
            else                        ; TaskBar right
                {
                    ;MsgBox TaskBar right
                    NewXpos := 0
                    NewYpos := 0
                    NewWidth := (TaskBarXpos / 2)
                }
        }
    ;MsgBox WinMove, A,, %NewXpos%, %NewYpos%, %NewWidth%, %NewHeight%
    WinRestore, A       ; if windows was maximized mode 
    WinMove, A,, NewXpos, NewYpos, NewWidth, NewHeight
    Return
    }

#Right::
    {
    GetTaskBarDetails()
    ;MsgBox, TaskBarXpos:`t%TaskBarXpos%`nTaskBarYpos:`t%TaskBarYpos%`nTaskBarWidth:`t%TaskBarWidth%`nTaskBarHeight:`t%TaskBarHeight%`nA_ScreenWidth:`t%A_ScreenWidth%`nA_ScreenHeight:`t%A_ScreenHeight%
    If  (TaskBarWidth * 1) >= (A_ScreenWidth * 1)       ; TaskBar on top or bottom
        {
            ;MsgBox TaskBar on top or bottom
            NewWidth := (A_ScreenWidth / 2)
            if  TaskBarYpos <= 0            ; TaskBar top
                {
                    ;MsgBox TaskBar top
                    NewXpos := (A_ScreenWidth / 2)
                    NewYpos := (TaskBarHeight + TaskBarYpos)
                    NewHeight := (A_ScreenHeight - (TaskBarHeight + TaskBarYpos))
                }   
            else                            ; TaskBar bottom
                {
                    ;MsgBox TaskBar bottom
                    NewXpos := (A_ScreenWidth / 2)
                    NewYpos := 0
                    NewHeight := TaskBarYpos
                }
        }
    else                                ; TaskBar left or right
        {
            ;MsgBox TaskBar TaskBar left or right
            NewHeight := A_ScreenHeight
            if  TaskBarXpos <= 0        ; TaskBar left
                {
                    ;MsgBox TaskBar left
                    NewWidth := ((A_ScreenWidth - (TaskBarWidth + TaskBarXpos)) / 2)
                    NewXpos := ((TaskBarWidth + TaskBarXpos) + NewWidth)
                    NewYpos := 0
                }
            else                        ; TaskBar right
                {
                    ;MsgBox TaskBar right
                    NewXpos := (TaskBarXpos / 2)
                    NewYpos := 0
                    NewWidth := (TaskBarXpos / 2)
                }
        }
    ;MsgBox WinMove, A,, %NewXpos%, %NewYpos%, %NewWidth%, %NewHeight%
    WinRestore, A       ; if windows was maximized mode 
    WinMove, A,, NewXpos, NewYpos, NewWidth, NewHeight
    Return
    }

#Up::           ; maximize window
    {
    WinRestore, A       ; if windows is in a false maximized mode 
    WinMaximize, A
    Return
    }

#Down::         ; minimize window
    {
    WinMinimize, A
    Return
    }
```

Comments and improvements are welcome, as usual.

Comment: If you press WIN+DOWN on Win7+ and the active window is maximized, it is restored, not minimized. To fix this, use
    `WinGet, st, MinMax, A`
    `if (st == 1) { WinRestore, A } else { WinMinimize, A }`

Comment: If you have a window "maxmized" to right respective left side of the screen and press WIN+LEFT or WIN+RIGHT (accordingly) afterwards, the window is *not* moved to the other side of the screen but restored to its previous state instead. To do this, the script would need to store the previous coordinates (position and size) for each window that is "maximized" to any side of the screen and store internally or check if a window is in "maximized to side of screen" state.

Comment: You are right. However, what I wanted to achieve was to split the screen in two parts, one window to the left, one window to the right, or one window maximised.

Comment: By the way, I wrote another script that allows, on wide screens, to center a window with a width of 1280px. See: https://github.com/gerdami/AutoHotkey/blob/master/WinCentered.ahk